# @Value inside class file in third party jar spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a migrating an old Spring XML config-based app to Spring Boot and there are third party jars which have `@Value("$` properties referenced in them. I tried loading a custom property file placed under `/resources` in the new Spring Boot workspace and loading it with `@PropertySource("classpath:file")` but during the Spring Boot run the property does not seem to be loaded and get this below error:

```
     Could not resolve placeholder 'com.example.propertyName' in value "${com.example.propertyName}"
     at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178) 
     ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Please share your pom.xml file and the error stacktrace

Comment: Add **com.example.propertyName=somevalue** to the properties file created in your resources folder.

Comment: Thanks. Also the bean i am trying to load (Configuration.class in the example link you provided) its inside a third party jar and without @Component annotation. So i am using xml config to load it. Also i added the property in my properties file under resources but still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the properties values using annotation @Value then mentioned the key on it.

you can follow the below link for end to end example

[click](http://www.jhaji.in/2018/03/external-configuration-binding.html)

Comment: Thanks. But the bean i am trying to load (Configuration.class in the example link you provided) its inside a third party jar and without @Component annotation. So i am using xml config to load it. Also i added the property in my properties file under resources but still doesn't work!